# Find a rectangle in an array with [x,y] point

Tags: data-structures

I'll do my best to make my case scenario simple.

1-) Let's suppose we need to stores a lot of rectangles in some kind of array/data structure. Each rectangle are of different sizes and are positioned at various parts of the screen. Rectangles can't overlap together.

2-) Then we click on the screen with the mouse at point [x,y].

Now, we need to determine if we clicked on a part of one of the rectangles. Well, that would be insane to iterate through all the rectangles to make some kind of comparisons, especially if there is a huge number of them.

What would be the fastest technique/algorithm to do it with as little steps as possible? What would be the best data structure to use in such case?

Comment: Can you tell how are you store rectangle co-ordinates?

Comment: Can you provide more info on the context? Is the set of rectangles static or dynamic? How often will you be clicking? If this is about gaming, look up "hitbox" and "hit detection".

Comment: Yes, it's a gaming context. I'm adding game objects of different width and height (in tile unit), and I need to know when the player (represented by a single tile) step on a part of them. The object will also move around on a 2d coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to store the rectangles: The root represents the whole area that contains all rectangles, and this area is then recursively subdivided as required.
If you want to test if a certain coordinate is within one of the rectangles, you start at the root, and walk down the tree until either you find a rectangle or not.
This can be done in O(log n) time.

Comment: Interesting, do you know a website or book that explain them painlessly? I've also just read about Interval Trees, could they be a good solution as well? Although Interval Trees seems to deal only with an axis.

Comment: The point of quadtrees is that they represent 2-dimensional sorting of objects. I did not use them by myself, so I don't have working code. But you could look up one of the links in the wiki article I cited above, namely <http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps>. This should give you an idea how to implement it.

Comment: I'll investigate Quad Tree today, I've also found some insights about Kd Trees.